# Why might Node perform different regex matching inside a script vs the repl?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm seeing some very strange behaviour with a little script I'm writing (and running with Node v6). If I place the following line in a script, say `index.js`:

```
console.log((/autonom.*/ig).test('autonomy'))
```

and run it with `node index.js`, I'm seeing `false`. Unexpected!

Stranger still is that if I open an interactive shell with `node`, and run:

```
> (/autonom.*/ig).test('autonomy')
true
```

I get `true`, as expected. Is there any reason why the code in the script would have a different effect to that in the repl?

**Edit** the regex had a little bit of spice for no real reason. I see the same behaviour even with the trivial:

```
console.log((/^autonomy$/).test('autonomy'))
```

**Edit** the plot thickens hugely:

```
console.log((/autonom\S*/i).test('autonomy'))
console.log((/autonom\S*/i).test('autonomy'))
```

`node index.js` with this file prints:

```
true
false
```

Comment: Remove the `g` modifier. `console.log(/autonom.*/i.test('autonomy'))`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no joy: even console.log((/^autonomy$/).test('autonomy')) prints false...

Comment: Note the brackets  - `console.log(/autonom.*/i.test('autonomy'))`

Comment: All of the examples return true in both scripts and repl for me (at least with node v6.9.1).

Comment: Both return `true` for me.. Node  v7.1.0  , Do you have any third party modules your loading with the script version??   Oh, and Chrome return true too, to complete the circle.. :)

Comment: This is very strange... if I save the file around a bit, copy - paste it from here, change node version in nvm, I sometimes see a true... Is there some kind of regex cache?!

Comment: Starts to sound like [data rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_degradation).

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got to the root of the problem, and thought I'd share an answer to the question!

Why might Node be behaving strangely in this situation?

The problem lies in where i took my original strings from - which happened to be to copy and paste from a PDF article. Let's take the string 'autonomy' for an example.

In Atom, my editor, this looked exactly like 'autonomy'. As it did when I pasted it to SO in the original question.

However, if I take the one in-editor and output it as a hex buffer, I see:

```
6175746f6e6f6d01
```

For comparison, the string 'autonomy', if typed out manually, is:

```
6175746f6e6f6d
```

Herein lies the problem. The reason it worked for all of you lot, and the reason it worked for me in the REPL, is that most of the places I pasted it (SO, bash, ...) didn't understand / threw out that final `01`, leaving you seeing the "proper" string 'autonomy' as it looks.

FYI, the ASCII character `01` is `SOH: Start of Header`. SHRUG!